# C function to return a char array generated with strcat in a for loop

Tags: c, strcat

I am trying to add 10 strings containing the word "data" in a char array and return the result.  Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    char* concat () {
       char src[50], dest[1];
       strcpy(src,  "data");

       int i =0;
       for (i=0; i<=10; i++) {
          strcat(dest, src);
          strcat(dest, ",");
       }
       return(dest);
    }

    int main () {
        printf("Final destination string : |%s|", concat());
        return 0;
    }
```

But when I return my `dest` char array I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Note that using `strcat()` repeatedly leads to quadratic behaviour (once you have the underlying memory management sorted out).  I was working with some colleagues on a reproduction of a customer problem, and they'd created code to generate 700,000 numbers in a big string using `strcat()`.  The program took about 70 seconds to run, generating a string of nearly 6 MiB.  I rewrote it to use `memmove()` instead of `strcat()`, and it took less than 0.1 seconds — a factor of about 700 difference.  Granted, that's an extreme case, but it shows the problem.  (Look up Shlemiel the Painter, too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*i can not return my dest char array, i have segmentation fault* => because `dest` is array of only one char, you can't store store `"data"` 10 times into `dest`. Instead of `dest[1]` , take `dest` as `char pointe`r and allocate memory dynamically.

you may want to do like below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char* concat () {
        char src[50], *dest;
        dest = malloc(100 * sizeof(char)); /* allocating 100 bytes for dest, allocate according to your requirement */
        strcpy(src,  "data");

        int i =0,j;
        for (i=0,j=0; i<=10; i++) {
                strcat(dest+j, src);//first time dest points to starting address
                strcat(dest, ",");
                j = strlen(dest);/* next time put data at dest+j location */
        }
        dest[j]= '\0';
        return dest ;
}
int main () {
        char * ret = NULL;
        printf("Final destination string : |%s|\n", ret = concat());
        free(ret); /* to avoid memory leakage */
        return 0;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: sizeof(char) is by definition always 1, so it's redundant to use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong idea that `strcat` allocates memory when it concatenates strings. *It is wrong*. So by using 1-length char array in `strcat` you have invoked undefined behavior because it will write to memory that is out of the bound of the single element `char` array.

Also the `dest` variable having automatic storage duration - you can't use it once the scope on which it is declared ends(which is in this case when the function ends). Using a variable after it's lifetime is over is undefined behavior.

Another thing is the `strcat`'s first parameter is null terminated char array which is not the case here, so it is also undefined behavior using the wrong parameter to the `strcat`.

Provided that `dest` can hold any concatenated string you are working on this function you can do this

```
char s[]="data";
char* dest = malloc(MAXLEN);
if(!dest){ perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
for(int i = 0; i <10; i++){
   if(!i) strcpy(dest,src);
   else
     strcat(dest,src);
   strcat(dest,",");
}
return dest;
```

In `main()`:

```
char *s;
printf("Final destination string : |%s|", (s=concat()));
free(s);
```

Comment: @achal.: Check carefully.

Comment: @achal.: Because it hold the memory of the allocated chunk returned by malloc in the function `concat`.

Comment: Ohh .. I didn't see it. Thanks